# ksh giving error in Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0

Tags: macos, installation, package, ksh, darwin

I've copied the latest version of ksh93 into the darwin computer but for some reason it doesn't work.

Whenever I execute anything with `ksh` (for example "ksh --version") this is the error that I get:

```
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT trap
```

Do you know what it might be?

My version is the following:

```
Darwin paramisx82614.fr.net.intra 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ast ksh downloads for Darwin require Mac OS X. So your kernel should be 10.x as well.

If you really need ksh for Darwin 9.x you will have to compile it from source.